# How to write relative xpath for radio button for an element in Mobile App using Appium

Tags: android, android-studio, xpath, appium, appium-android

I am trying to automate my Mobile APP where I have a scenario to change 2 or more cards. These cards are displayed in radio button and I have to choose among these cards

The absolute xpath for 1st radio button is

```
/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.FrameLayout[2]/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.RelativeLayout/android.widget.ScrollView/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.RadioButton
```

The absolute xpath for 2nd radio button is

```
/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.FrameLayout[2]/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.RelativeLayout/android.widget.ScrollView/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout[2]/android.widget.RadioButton
```

There are no other significant properties for this radio buttons to write relative xpath.

How to write relative xpath for this?

Attaching screenshot for the same. Appreciate your response.Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the bellow `xpath`:

```
(//*[contains(@class,'RadioButton')])[2]
```

The above for second radio button.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to select the radio buttons:

First radio button:

```
//android.widget.RadioButton[1]
```

Second radio button:

```
//android.widget.RadioButton[2]
```

If you want to be more specific, you can use:

```
//android.widget.ScrollView//android.widget.RadioButton[1]
//android.widget.ScrollView//android.widget.RadioButton[2]
```

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: @ChaitanyaMaligi Is there a reason you removed this solution as the accepted answer for your question? If the answer is incorrect or inaccurate then I would like to fix / improve it.